# PHP Code to generate this

Tags: php, xml, soap, nonce, usernametoken

I'm trying to get a result from a wsdl file, It however requires authentication and the normal passing of an username and password gives me an error:

```
Error arguments: 
    Missing authentication from header
```

The header should look like the one below;

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">jfdkfjdskfjdsklfjsdkf==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>TIMESTAMP</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

Comment: authentication + header would imply to me that the service is missing http basic authentication stuff.

Comment: @MarcB unless ws-security is used :) header could point to the envelope.